# UIScroll View on IOS 7 lingo

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, autolayout

okay, my app was built on for iOS 6 until iOS 7 got released and i started making changes to support both versions. Now, i'm having problems with UScrollView and it's constraints on storyboard.  when i add a scroll view to my view which has a navigation bar and add a button (or any subview) for say 20 points under the navigation bar, at runtime the subview get's misplaced vertically. it moves downwards in like 60 points. i guess the same size as the navi bar and the status bar combined. So, i was pulling my hair to know how to fix it with constraints and auto layout but i couldn't figure out how. the app sometimes crashes with a certain mix of layouts. However, what i did was to pull the scroll view aside and place the subviews as i want them to look like with navi bar there, then i pulled it back in it's right place (covering the entire view) and when i run the app it all works as expected. now the question what constraints should i add so that it works as expected without doing the whole process aside and then adding it? right now my view looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the button is under the navi bar. but when i runt he app it gets under the bar as i want it to. so how can i just add it on story board under the bar and let it stay there? in iOS 6 i used to do it that way without worrying and ios 7 seems like doing this hard on us.